# How to keep objects looking aligned when modelling cars?

Tags: modeling, materials, lighting

as I have been modelling cars using a method of subdividing individual panels I have noticed that there is a major problem that arises with this method that prevents my cars looking like most on the internet.

Gloss line discrepancies in the panels like so:
[image]

When I look at other models and renders the shading and behavior on the objects match and look correct:

Mike Pan's BMW:
[image]
Another BMW render with correct shading:
[image]

I realise that not having the vertices aligned (and the havoc subsurf modifiers can wreak) means the materials will not look right and Mike Pan's model is one object for the shell of the car. Is modelling in panels the "wrong" way and I should switch to a single shell? Or is there a standard method in subsurf panel (or other schemes of) modelling to keep the natural look?

Comment: Shrink Wrap again.  Look at the related items on the right side of this page.  There are techniques of shrink wrapping surfaces to minimize gloss line discrepancies.  There are also videos on the website that rhymes with noonoob.  I will not have time at the moment to search for you.

Comment: If you want to learn how to avoid these issues plus others, I highly recommend Mastering Car Modelling by CG Masters it's by Chris Plush - its a paid course